# how to pass textbox target value onchange event and change object properties using hooks

Tags: react-hooks, onchange

> to update the complete object properties by using useState
>
> > pass textbox target value onchange event and change object properties using hooks

```
function ExampleObjectHooks() {

    const [name, setname] = useState({ first: '', last: '' });

    const onInputNameChange = (e) => {
        setname({ first: e.target.value, last: e.target.value });
        console.log(name);
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <input type="text" onChange={(e) => onInputNameChange(e)} ></input>
                <input type="text" onChange={e => onInputNameChange(e)} ></input>
            </form>
            {name.first}{name.last}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an `name` attribute to each `input` field, and update the state using the name (`key` in the code). Node that you need to merge the state of each field by yourself. To so spread the previous state, and override the field you've just updated.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function ExampleObjectHooks() {

  const [name, setname] = useState({ first: '', last: '' });

  const onInputNameChange = ({ target }) => {
    const { name: key, value } = target;
    
    setname(state => ({
      ...state,
      [key]: value
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input name="first" type="text" onChange={onInputNameChange} ></input>
        <input name="last" type="text" onChange={onInputNameChange} ></input>
      </form>
      {name.first} {name.last}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ExampleObjectHooks />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ori Drori for the quick response and the solution

Comment: You're welcome. Accept the answer, if it solved your problem.